# Can android studio emulator run without `adb`?

Tags: adb, android-emulator

I want to run android-studio emulator without having an `adb`.

On running the emulator It checks for the `adb.exe` using `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` environment variable and exits if there is no valid one(valid one = having an `adb`).

How to run the emulator without having the `adb`? Is there a command enabling running the emulator without the `adb` or something like that?

Comment: Could you explain what you are actually trying to do or why you want to run the emulator without adb?

Comment: @Robert I want to run it on a platform that doesn't have a compatible `adb` and I want to save the resources since I don't need it.

Comment: Well the emulator is open source. You can try to modify the sources and build your own version.

Comment: @Robert yeah I know that but do I have to remove the dependencies on `adb` manually or there is a parameter I can pass to make it work without the `adb`?

Answer (score 0):

The emulator's [command line options](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline) don't include anything for working without adb, and several options implicitly assume adb will be in use. I suspect, though I don't know for sure, that Android Studio uses adb to communicate with the emulator.

It looks as if you'll need to change the emulator to run it without adb.